# Whats the right strategy of when to create jobs and sub jobs in sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, jobs, sidekiq

So I have a system that receives messages from devices and then it goes through 3 different servers and countless of services are run on each job. From an architecture perspective, whats certain considerations in using sidekiq to make my program async? Are there downsides to making sub processes run using sidekiq. Any advice?

Comment: Why is this a bad question? It just seems like a hard question.

Answer (score 0):

architecture(system design) should be based on the problems you are trying to solve. if your services are design to unique business domains and if they are async compatible then you can spawn sub jobs for each service. but if not or your need flexible transactions among services then job per request is the right choice. so you may have both of these implementations in your system based on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The upside to making your program async with sidekiq is that it is easy and produces good reporting in case of an error. The downsides of using sidekiq for this task is that there is a lot of overhead creating and executing the jobs. This could become such a problem that it represents the majority of the resources used.